# New Qt Directory is not valid

Tags: macos, qt, qt4

I've written an application using Qt on OS X. The installed SDK automatically installed as a framework which I didn't want. So I cloned their newest version from the Qt git repository and built it from source as static libraries. I would like it to compile using those static libraries instead of the framework but in preferences in setting the version/Path of Qt no matter what path I direct it to it says it's not a valid Qt directory. What has to be in a qt Directory that constitutes it being valid?

Comment: Which preferences are you referring to? Are you using some IDE or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this, The problem was installing on OSX I needed to declare -no-framework when running configure.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips;

- Install into a path that doesn't contain spaces
- Use -prefix $PWD from the current path, and set the PATH, INCLUDE and LIB env variables appropriately - this makes it possible to have multiple Qt builds, e.g. multiple shadow builds from one source directory
- Don't do static configure - it makes using plugins difficult, and assuming you use LGPL you have to ship the .o files.